# What function should I use to fit this data? Logistic function is not good enough fit.

Tags: functions, data-analysis

I'm using curve_fit from numpy to try an fit some data I have. The function I used was the logistic function defined http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function 
and the parameters I picked were 
(0.026, 0.745, 19.0, 0.0005), for L, k, x0, and an extra parameter a. 
I tested the goodness of fit using chi-squared test. The test said it was a bad fit, and it is visibly a bad fit from the picture shown below. 
[image: fit is blue data is red]

I'm not sure if what other function would be better to fit this data, and if this is a good function what parameters should I change?

Comment: Tried a polynomial of not too high degree? Or, since probably $y$ is not allowed to become negative, have you tried fitting $\ln y$ against suitable functions instead?

Comment: Do you mean plot ln(y) instead? I tried doing that, and The graph appears to be a logarithm with a slight tail